# How can i resolve loading issue on android emulator?

Tags: android

i recently dropped a table in an android application using sqlite3 from the adb shell.
When i subsequently restarted the application it notified me that the 'android.process.acore' had crashed..but the activity still came on.The issue now is whenever i want to start the emulator it just stops at the stage with the notification (in the eclipse IDE..after it notifies  that an emulator was LAUNCHED) ... " Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...." and it just hangs there.The emulator does not come on.what can i do now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Uninstalling and running the application again`

Comment: U mean uninstalling eclipse or the adt plugin? BTW it was working perfectly before i dropped the table.

Comment: No, the application using sqlite